# Help with Basic Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

Could you help me find the problem with my custom Trigger? In a nutshell, I would like a picklist field called “Housekeeping_Status__c” to be updated to ‘Clean’ when the Account Id on one object (Housekeeping__c), is the exact account Id on another object (Property_Rate__c). Each object is unrelated but both share the same parent Account. This trigger should run (after insert, after update).

I should also mention that I have a second Housekeeping__c trigger (“Before insert, before update”) which populates the Account__r.Id on the Housekeeping__c record. I have no problem with this trigger.

Here is the broken code:

```
trigger setToClean on Housekeeping__c (after insert, after update)
{

     for (Housekeeping__c housekeeping : Trigger.new)
     {
           String houseaccount = housekeeping.Account__r.Id;

           List<Property_Rate__c> findRates = [SELECT Id FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Account__r.Id = :houseaccount];

           for (Property_Rate__c currentRate : findRates)
           {
               currentRate.Housekeeping_Status__c = ‘Cleaned';
           }

     }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? anyway you are not retrieving the field `Housekeeping_Status__c` even you are trying to access it in the trigger.

Comment: The problem is that the Housekeeping_Status__c on each of the Property_Rate__c objects is not updating. 

I should clarify that the Housekeeping_Status__c is a field within Property_Rate__c.

Comment: Okay, I've tried adding Housekeeping_Status__c into the findRates SOQL query. The Housekeeping_Status__c is still not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE : Applied @snehakem suggestion

You are assigning the new value for the field but not updating the records. Just perform required DML.

```
trigger setToClean on Housekeeping__c (after insert, after update)
{
    List<Property_Rate__c> updatedPropertyList = new List<Property_Rate__c>();
    Set<String> accountIds = new Set<String>();

    for(Housekeeping__c housekeeping : Trigger.new){
        accountIds.add(housekeeping.Account__c);
    }

    List<Property_Rate__c> findRates = [SELECT Id, Housekeeping_Status__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Account__r.Id IN :accountIds];

    for (Property_Rate__c currentRate : findRates)
    {
       currentRate.Housekeeping_Status__c = 'Cleaned';
       updatedPropertyList.add(currentRate);
    }

    update updatedPropertyList;  // This is what you are missing     
}
```

NOTE: This suggestion(not compiled and tested) is just for resolving your field not updating issue. Addition to that have a look at for the code if it's satisfying your requirement (I feel like you need some conditional statement). 
Also note that it's not a good idea to have multiple triggers on same object as in [documentations](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices).

Comment: Thanks highfive. I got the following error message when attempting to update the a Property_Rate__c record: 

Apex trigger setToClean caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: setToClean: System.LimitException: Too many DML rows: 10001

Any thoughts?

Comment: You never query inside for loop. Also you cant access parent fields like housekeeping.Account__r.Id this as it comes from trigger.New, Instead you can directly use housekeeping.Account__c

Comment: You will not put update statements inside `for` loops, have a look at my code again. @snehakem agreed and I've updated the answer

Comment: But still you query inside for loop. I think thats not a bulkified code. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
trigger setToClean on Housekeeping__c (after insert, after update)

    List<Property_Rate__c> listToBeUpdated = new List<Property_Rate__c>();
        Set<Id> setAccId = new Set<Id>();

         for (Housekeeping__c housekeeping : Trigger.new)
         {
            setAccId.add(housekeeping.Account__c);
         }

         Map<Id,Property_Rate__c> mapAccIdProperty = new ap<Id,Property_Rate__c>();//Query outside for loop

         for(Property_Rate__c p :[SELECT Id,Account__c FROM Property_Rate__c WHERE Account__c = :setAccId]){
            mapAccIdProperty.put(p.Account__c,p);
         }
         for (Housekeeping__c housekeeping : Trigger.new)
         {
           if(housekeeping.Account__c!=null && mapAccIdProperty.keyset().contains(housekeeping.Account__c)){
                mapAccIdProperty.get(housekeeping.Account__c).Housekeeping_Status__c = ‘Cleaned';
                listToBeUpdated.add(mapAccIdProperty.get(housekeeping.Account__c));
           }   

         }
     if(listToBeUpdated.size()>0){
        update listToBeUpdated;    
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to help!

Snehakem, I first tried your solution. For the first time, the trigger worked! But it only updated one of the records attached to the account.

Highfive, I tried your updated solution and all associated records were updated! I will have to look through documentation to better understand the modifications that you made. 

Thank you both once again!
Alex